android.system.GaiException: Okhhtp issue come daily
I am using retrofit for API calls, In Firebase lots of issues come for the OKHttp issue (android.system.GaiException: exceptions) but in real devices not facing these issues..only shows in Firebase.
issues:
1.java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException - Trust anchor for certification path not found
2.android.system.GaiException - android_getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
I have try change flow of retrofit calling but not working.
